# Conditional inserting of data from pandas data frame to HANA table in python and SQL

Tags: python, sql, hana

unfortunately I am not able to find the solution that's why I hope that you can help me please.

*Given:*

I have a table in HANA called `Table_1`.
It looks like following: (`ID` = Primary Key)

| ID | COL1 | NAME | COL2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | someValue | A | someValue |
| 2 | someValue | B | someValue |

I have a CSV File with an **unknown number of columns and unknown column names**. The only thing I know is, that each CSV file contains a column called `X_ID` and `X_NAME`.

I read this CSV file to a pandas dataframe called `df`.

`Df` looks like following:

| X_ID | X_NAME | COL3 | COL4 | COL... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | someXValue | someXValue | ... |
| 2 | B | someXValue | someXValue |  |
| 3 | C | someXValue | someXValue |  |

The following applies for `Table_1` and `df`:

```
ID = X_ID and NAME = X_NAME
```

Now I want to include the data of the `df` to `Table_1`.

I tried it with Merge, Insert and Upsert but unfortunately I couldn't get a command to run properly.

If the `X_ID` is already included in `ID` in `Table_1` than only the new columns from the `df` should be appended to the corresponding row.

If `X_ID` is not in `ID` than it should be  applied the following:
`ID = X_ID, NAME = X_NAME`; `COL1` and `COL2` from `Table_1` should be null; and all the additional columns and their values from the `df` should be included.

The solution should look like this:

`Table_1`:

| ID | COL1 | NAME | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | someValue | A | someValue | someXValue | someXValue | ... |
| 2 | someValue | B | someValue | someXValue | someXValue |  |
| 3 | null | C | null | someXValue | someXValue |  |

*What I already tried:*

My current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pandas as pd
import argparse
from hdbcli import dbapi

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
                    prog='ABC',
                    description='XYZ')

parser.add_argument('input_filepath')
args = parser.parse_args()

df = pd.read_csv(args.input_filepath,sep=',')

conn = dbapi.connect(address='ADDRESS', port=PORT, user='USER', password='PSW')

target_table = 'TABLE_NAME'

sql_insert_template = f"""
ALTER TABLE {target_table}
    ADD ({', '.join([f'{col} VARCHAR(200)' for col in df.columns if col != 'X_ID' and col != 'X_NAME'])});

# TODO: SQL Code for data inserting (at the bottom)
"""

try:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql_insert_template)

    conn.commit()

    print("Record inserted successfully")
finally:
    conn.close()
```

I tried following SQL Code for inserting the data:

```
MERGE INTO {target_table} AS target
USING (
    SELECT
        {', '.join(df.columns)}
    FROM {df}
) AS source
ON (target.ID = source.X_ID)

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE {target_table} 
        SET {', '.join([f'target.{col} = source.{col}' for col in df.columns if col != 'X_ID' and col != 'X_NAME'])}

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT INTO  {target_table}(
        ID, NAME, {', '.join(f'{col}' for col in df.columns if col != 'X_ID' and col != 'X_NAME')}
    ) VALUES (
        {', '.join([f'source.X_ID, source.X_NAME, source.{col}' for col in df.columns if col != 'X_ID' and col != 'X_NAME'])}
    );
```

In this command there are multiple errors. The first one is a syntax error I was not able to solve near Merge and the second one is getting the values from the `df`. Because right now in the part "`WHEN NOT MATCHED THAN ... VALUES()`" not the values but the column names are included as values and the iteration over the `df` rows, columns and thus values is wrong. So right now only "one row" gets included (one row but with column names instead of values). But I want to include all the rows, values of `df` to be included in one single SQL command.

I really have no idea how to solve the problem that all values are included the right way.

The second approach I tried was with UPSET, but there still is the problem of including the values. And there is the additional current problem that I needed to know how many columns `table_1` has, so that I can set the "null" values.

```
UPSERT {target_table}
VALUES({', '.join(f'{col}' for col in df.columns if col == 'X_ID')}, null, {', '.join(f'{col}' for col in df.columns if col == 'X_NAME')}, null, {', '.join(f'{col}' for col in df.columns if col != 'X_ID' and col != 'X_NAME')})
#WITH PRIMARY KEY;
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with Pandas Dataframes and SAP HANA, I would recommend to have a look at the [hana-ml Python package](https://pypi.org/project/hana-ml/). It's build upon `hdbcli` and improves the integration with Pandas significantly. Have a look at the [HANA Dataframe](https://help.sap.com/doc/cd94b08fe2e041c2ba778374572ddba9/2023_3_QRC/en-US/hana_ml.dataframe.html#hana_ml.dataframe.DataFrame) and specifically methods [create_dataframe_from_pandas](https://help.sap.com/doc/cd94b08fe2e041c2ba778374572ddba9/2023_3_QRC/en-US/hana_ml.dataframe.html#hana_ml.dataframe.create_dataframe_from_pandas) and [save](https://help.sap.com/doc/cd94b08fe2e041c2ba778374572ddba9/2023_3_QRC/en-US/hana_ml.dataframe.html#hana_ml.dataframe.DataFrame.save)

However, this is not yet a solution to your initial problem. It seems like the data model, you have chosen, is not perfectly suitable for your use case. If each new table really comes with arbitrary attributes, you will end up with a very wide and sparse table on HANA. In the relational world, you may consider having one table with `ID` and `NAME` and a second table with key-value-pairs referencing the common attributes.

It would be even easier to use [SAP HANA's JSON Document Store](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/3e48dd3ad36e41efbdf534a89fdf278f/dca379e9c94940e998d9d4b5c656d1bd.html), which is a native engine for managing semi-structured data. In this scenario, you would use [to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) on the Pandas dataframe and [create_collection_from_elements](https://help.sap.com/doc/cd94b08fe2e041c2ba778374572ddba9/2023_3_QRC/en-US/hana_ml.docstore.html#hana_ml.docstore.create_collection_from_elements) in `hana-ml`. The resulting JSON collection can be queried with a simple SQL.